# Setting value to a dataframe using df.loc updates a copy of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

```
import pandas as pd

#Inserting some data into name_df 

list_name = ["Al","Brad"]  
list_age = [20,30]

name_df = pd.DataFrame(list_name,columns=["name"])  
age_df = pd.DataFrame(list_age,columns=["age"])

name_df = pd.concat([name_df,age_df],axis=1)

**#Make a copy of the dataframe**  
copy_df = name_df  

**#Editing the data in name_df**  
name_df.loc[name_df["name"]=="Brad", ["age"]] = 35

**#Change appears in copy_df**  
print(copy_df)
```

Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: `copy_df = name_df ` is **NOT** creating a copy. Its just a reference to the SAME object.

Comment: See my answer - a copy is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy. (`copy.deepcopy()`)

```
import pandas as pd
import copy 
list_name = ["Al","Brad"]  
list_age = [20,30]

name_df = pd.DataFrame(list_name,columns=["name"])  
age_df = pd.DataFrame(list_age,columns=["age"])

name_df = pd.concat([name_df,age_df],axis=1)

copy_df = copy.deepcopy(name_df)  

name_df.loc[name_df["name"]=="Brad", ["age"]] = 35

print(copy_df)
```

Comment: a=10

b=a

a=9


print(b)

Alright, thanks. It's different for a variable.